# Problema de codificación en python �

Tags: python, jython

Buenas,

Tengo un script en python que accede a una base de datos acces. Los datos a los que accede me los tiene que devolver por la consola al lanzar el script, pero el problema es que si alguna palabra tiene tilde o es una "Ñ" me sustituye ese caracter por un cuadrado negro, que al pegarlo se traduce en un rombo con una interrogación -->  **"aplicaci�n de Gesti�n"**.

He probado con funciones que he encontrado por internet, he probado a cambiar la codificación pero no funciona, no se si es que hago algo mal con tanto lio de codificación o que.

Lo que necesito es saber como puedo hacer para sustituir la letra con tilde por la letra sin tilde o como sustituir este símbolo por un punto por ejemplo.

Este es mi método de conexión al archivo access:

`driver_class = "net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanloadDriver" 
cnxn = zxJDBC.connect(jdbc_url, username, password,driver_class)`

donde jdbc_url es la ruta al archivo access dentro de la máquina linux

Gracias.

Comment: ¿Qué servidor de bases de datos usas y qué código de conexión? Si es MySQL consulta este enlace para conocer cómo establecer el juego de caracteres correcto (parece que están almacenados usando ISO-8859-xx) y posteriormente pasarlo a UTF-8 o el que use tu aplicación con `.decode('iso-8859-xx').encode('utf8')`: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-connectargs.html

Comment: @OscarGarcia la BD es un archivo access y nunca había trabajado con uno, y no se mirar la codificación.... siento mi ignorancia.. y gracias por responder

Comment: Si es un archivo access entonces el problema es que estás en Windows, la codificación de caracteres será (probablemente) ISO-8859-15, por lo que deberás usar el código que te puse para convertir las cadenas: `cadena.decode('iso-8859-15').encode('utf8')`.

Comment: Si el trozo de código proporcionado te ayudó házmelo saber para que te redacte una respuesta con la explicación y enlaces a la documentación de python. Si no, agradecería un [ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) para poder proporcionarte código exacto con la respuesta.

Comment: @OscarGarcia me sigue sacando el cuadradito por la consola... no se si tendrá que ver que lanzo todo desde ubuntu, porque el archivo access lo tengo en una máquina ubuntu y es donde lanzo el srcipt. driver_class = "net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanloadDriver" cnxn = zxJDBC.connect(jdbc_url, username, password,driver_class) donde jdbc_url es la ruta al archivo access dentro de la máquina linux

Answer (score 4):

Estás sufriendo un problema con el juego de caracteres que usa el archivo access (probablemente `latin9/iso-8859-15`) que debes traducir a `utf8`, que es el que usa tu sistema operativo, antes de mostrarlo en pantalla o bien en una web que use `utf8`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

cadena = "Aplicaci\xf3n de Gesti\xf3n"
print("Antes: " + cadena)
print("Después: " + cadena.decode('iso-8859-15').encode('utf8'))
```

Resultado:

```
$ python ejemplo.py
Antes: Aplicaci�n de Gesti�n
Después: Aplicación de Gestión
```

Para hacer el trabajo hacemos uso de las funciones [`str.decode()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.decode) y [`str.encode()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.encode) indicando los juegos de caracteres origen y destino.

Comment: Me arroja este error: UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\ufffd' in position 36: ordinal not in range(128) PD: gracias por la ayuda :D

Comment: De nada, ¿podrías indicarme cómo has usado las funciones que te propuse para ver por qué trata de convertirlo a ascii? ¿Has usado `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` en la parte superior de tu script?

Comment: parte superior: #!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-         instrucciones que tu me pasaste: etiqueta = etiqueta.decode('iso-8859-15').encode('utf8')

Comment: ¿Podrías decirme en hexadecimal (puedes usar [`hexdump`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/hexdump)) el contenido de la cadena para reproducir el problema?

Comment: Esto es --> 61706c6963616369f36e206465204765737469f36e

Comment: Acabo de probarlo con `cadena = "\x61\x70\x6c\x69\x63\x61\x63\x69\xf3\x6e\x20\x64\x65\x20\x47\x65\x73\x74\x69\xf3\x6e"` y me ha funcionado bien.

Comment: entonces codifico la cadena en hexadecimal antes de hacer el decode?

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71388/discussion-between-oscargarcia-and-g3l0).

Answer (score 1):

Haciendo `print(type(descripcion))` los datos llegan como `unicode` y el valor del caracter es `\ufffd` asi que se elimina de la cadena o se sustituye por otro y así consigues librarte del problema: `descripcion = descripcion.replace(u'\ufffd','')`

Me he basado en este post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13093727/how-to-replace-unicode-characters-in-string-with-something-else-python